# Directory argument for Bowtie2

Tags: bioinformatics, bowtie2

I'm using the software [Bowtie 2](https://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/index.shtml) which aligns genome sequences. I have all my indexes in a directory `miniReference1`.

When I call Bowtie2 with the `-x <dir>` option I get the error that my index is not a Bowtie 2 index. What am I doing wrong? Below is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time here and I don't know why the pic wasn't uploaded. (Thanks for the useful correction)

Comment: And right, I am using bowtie2 for alignment and this is my code // bowtie2 -x miniReference -1 Sample_R1_trimmed.fq -2 Sample_R2_trimmed.fq -S Align

Answer (score 1):

The `-x` argument takes the path to the basename of the index. That means, if the index called `miniReference1.{suffix}` is inside a folder also called `miniReference1` then it must be `-x path/to/miniReference1/miniReference1`. There is no need to use this variable, just use the plain path.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue running `bowtie 2.5.0` against index files built by `bowtie 2.4.5`. The error message shows `readU: No such file or directory` even though the files are there.

[image]

I rebuilt the indexes using `bowtie 2.5.0` and the issue was resolved. So I'd suggest rebuilding the indexes using the same version as the aligner, and then running it again.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quoting the relevant part of the [manual](https://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml):

> **-x**           The basename of the index for the reference genome. The basename is the name of any of the index **files** up to but not including the final .1.bt2 / .rev.1.bt2 / etc. bowtie2 looks for the specified index first in the current directory, then in the directory specified in the **BOWTIE2_INDEXES environment variable.** [Emphasis by me.]

After reading this, I assume that what was missing is to tell BowTie2 the directory it is supposed to look in by setting the environment variable BOWTIE2_INDEXES. In bash you would do that by issuing the command

`export BOWTIE2_INDEXES=miniReference1`

If that doesn't help try to provide the absolute path. It is unclear to me whether Bowtie2 expects a Posix path name like `/c/Users/raghdad/Documents/project-x/sequences/miniReference1` or a Windows path name like `C:\Users\...`. (`pwd` in your terminal gives you the Posix name for the current  directory).

The `-x` file base name argument, `miniReference1`, is correct but does not name a directory; instead, it tells BowTie2 the set of indexes you want to work with, which is identified by the common "base name" of the files (the part up to the first dot). The reason for this scheme is probably that you could have different sets of indexes in the same directory, and each set would have a distinct and unique base name. Of course your way of putting each set in its own directory appears to be much cleaner, unless there is a reason to assess several index sets in one go.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this command (export BOWTIE2_INDEXES=miniReference1) and it gives this error (bowtie2-align exited with value 1)

Comment: Again I wrote the full path of the index but gives me the same error ( "miniReference1" does not exist or is not a Bowtie 2 index)

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm seeing the same errors too. All the input files are there, but somehow bowtie2 is not reading it.

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut You may want to ask the OP, Raghdad. I have never used the program but simply checked the manual. Apparently what I understood doesn't work or can be achieved easier with AtPoint's answer. Did you try supplying the entire path to the index file as suggested by AtPojnt?

Comment: Yes, I've tried supplying the whole directory, but bowtie2 still fails to get the files and directory. I'm using Bowtie2 2.5.0 from Bioconda, running on mac. My friend was able to run it just fine, so there might be a probem with my installation.

Comment: I think the issue was with the index files. They were built using Bowtie 2.4.5. The index files were rebuilt using Bowtie 2.5.0 and they work now.

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut That is very interesting and may bite a few more users. Do you want to write a short answer explaining that? I could do it as well but it's your finding!

Comment: Added the answer :)